# Why is my program not separately reading the else statement in my while loop at the end. Whatever I do it is always including that else

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

Here is my code:

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```c++
int main()
{
    do
    {
        int sideA, sideB, sideC;
        cout << "Please enter side A: ";
        cin >> sideA;
        while (sideA < 0) {
            cout << "Value entered must be positive!" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter side A: ";
            cin >> sideA;
        }
        cout << "Please enter side B: ";
        cin >> sideB;
        while (sideB < 0) {
            cout << "Value entered must be positive!" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter side B: ";
            cin >> sideB;
        }
        cout << "Please enter side C: ";
        cin >> sideC;
        while (sideC < 0) {
            cout << "Value entered must be positive!" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter side C: ";
            cin >> sideC;
        }
        int aSquare = sideA * sideA;
        int bSquare = sideB * sideB;
        int cSquare = sideC * sideC;
        if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC && sideB == sideC)
            cout << "This is an EQUILATERAL triangle!(all sides are equal)" << endl;
        else if (sideA == sideB && sideA != sideC && sideB != sideC)
            cout << "This is an ISOSCELES triangle, where only two sides are equal" << endl;
        else if (sideA != sideB && sideA == sideC && sideB != sideC)
            cout << "This is an ISOSCELES triangle, where only two sides are equal" << endl;
        else if (sideA != sideB && sideA != sideC && sideB == sideC)
            cout << "This is an ISOSCELES triangle, where only two sides are equal" << endl;
        else if (cSquare==aSquare+bSquare)
            cout << "This is a RIGHT triangle!" << endl;
        else if (aSquare == cSquare + bSquare)
            cout << "This is a RIGHT triangle!" << endl;
        else if (bSquare == aSquare + cSquare)
            cout << "This is a RIGHT triangle!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "This is a OTHER kind of triangle, not ISOSCELES, not RIGHT, not EQUILATERAL" << endl;
        int repeat;
        cout << "Would you like to repeat( 1-YES, 2-NO)";
        cin >> repeat;
        if (repeat == 1)
            continue;
        if (repeat == 2)
            break;
    }
    while (true);
}
````

It should not state the statement: "This is a OTHER kind of triangle, not ISOSCELES, not RIGHT, not EQUILATERAL". it also does do the equilateral and right conditions correct but does not even go into the else if for isosceles.

I've tried a lot of things but to no avail.

Sample output:

```
Please enter side A: 1
Please enter side B: -10
Value entered must be positive!
Please enter side B: 1
Please enter side C: 1
This is an EQUILATERAL triangle!(all sides are equal)
This is a OTHER kind of triangle, not ISOSCELES, not RIGHT, not EQUILATERAL
Would you like to repeat( 1-YES, 2-NO)
1
Please enter side A: 1
Please enter side B: 1
Please enter side C: 2
This is a OTHER kind of triangle, not ISOSCELES, not RIGHT, not EQUILATERAL
Would you like to repeat( 1-YES, 2-NO)
```

Comment: To format code here, paste it into the editor, select the code part, and click the Code icon in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    while (true) { 
        int sideA, sideB, sideC; 
        cout << "Please enter side A: "; 
        cin >> sideA; 
        while (sideA < 0) { 
            cout << "Value entered must be positive!" << endl; 
            cout << "Please enter side A: "; 
            cin >> sideA; 
        } 
        cout << "Please enter side B: "; 
        cin >> sideB; 
        while (sideB < 0) {     
            cout << "Value entered must be positive!" << endl; 
            cout << "Please enter side B: "; 
            cin >> sideB; 
        } 
        cout << "Please enter side C: "; 
        cin >> sideC; 
        while (sideC < 0) { 
            cout << "Value entered must be positive!" << endl; 
            cout << "Please enter side C: "; 
            cin >> sideC; 
        } 
        int aSquare = sideA * sideA; 
        int bSquare = sideB * sideB; 
        int cSquare = sideC * sideC; 
        if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC && sideB == sideC) 
            cout << "This is an EQUILATERAL triangle!(all sides are equal)" << endl; 
        else if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC && sideB != sideC) 
            cout << "This is an ISOSCELES triangle, where only two sides are equal" << endl; 
        else if (sideA == sideB && sideA != sideC && sideB == sideC) 
            cout << "This is an ISOSCELES triangle, where only two sides are equal" << endl; 
        else if (sideA != sideB && sideA == sideC && sideB == sideC) 
            cout << "This is an ISOSCELES triangle, where only two sides are equal" << endl;
        else if (cSquare==aSquare+bSquare)
            cout << "This is a RIGHT triangle!" << endl;
        else if (aSquare == cSquare + bSquare)
            cout << "This is a RIGHT triangle!" << endl;
        else if (bSquare == aSquare + cSquare)
            cout << "This is a RIGHT triangle!" << endl;
        else
                cout << "This is a OTHER kind of triangle, not ISOSCELES, not RIGHT, not EQUILATERAL" << endl;
        int repeat;
            cout << "Would you like to repeat( 1-YES, 2-NO)";
            cin >> repeat;
        if (repeat == 1)
            continue;
        if (repeat == 2)
            break;
    }
}
```

```
Please enter side A: 1
Please enter side B: 1
Please enter side C: 1
This is an EQUILATERAL triangle!(all sides are equal)
Would you like to repeat( 1-YES, 2-NO)2
```

Comment: thank you! i am not sure why it didnt work in the first place. wierd.